# How to set the height of a frame?

Tags: html, frameset

How to set the height of a frame used within a frameset in HTML?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `<frameset>` and `<frame>` tags, you'll need to programmatically set the `<frameset>`'s `rows` property to reflect the new height. This will include:

Getting a reference to the `<frameset>` DOM element from wherever the script is being called. The following example retrieves the first `<frameset>` element in the outer-most document:

```
var frset = top.document.getElementsByTagName("frameset")[0];
```

Setting the `rows` property. You specify it in the same format as you would writing writing the original HTML (comma delimited, with one entry per element, and * representing 'remaining space'). In the following example, `newHeight` is assumed to contain the new height for the top frame in a two-frame frameset.

```
frset.rows = newHeight.toString() + ", *";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the

[height](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/present/frames.html#adef-height-IFRAME)

property which specifies the height of the inline frame.