# framesets and frame in SAS changing the height

Tags: css, height, frame, sas, frameset

I am updating and very old site that is using framesets.  In the right 70% column I am attempting to force a height to accommodate a drop down menu.  For some reason when I give the frame an ID and a height it is ignored. Any ideas why this may be happening?  This is in a SAS environment, and I've never seen anyone use actually use framesets.

```
<frameset cols="30%, 70%">
  <frame src="left">
  <frame src="right" id="beTall">  
</frameset>
```

Answer (score 1):

A html with a frameset cannot be used to also display something on the screen. It's just a placeholder to divide the windows in multiple frames. Your frameset consists of two columns which are both 100% of the height viewport.

If you want to add a drop down menu, you need to add it to the html-file that contains the displayed content. In your example this is either left or right.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe `<frame>` supports a height attribute.  You may be able to achieve a similar result by wrapping a DIV around the entire frame source, IE, in "left" you have

```
<html>
<div id="beTall">
... source of left ...
</div>
</html>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_frame.asp

Comment: No luck it's locked at 75px and will not go beyond that, nothing in inline styles, css files or scripts.  It must have something to do with SAS.

Comment: What SAS product are you using to produce the frameset?

Comment: You might also want to look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648355/how-to-set-the-height-of-a-frame .  Also, note that the FRAMESET is what would control the height in terms of attributes, not the individual frame - both frames must be the same height.

Comment: I'm only making updates but, the IDE I am using is SAS Enterprise Guide 5.1.  Height seems only to work in iFrames and not on frames.  I'll try the JS approach.

Comment: I meant, how are you producing web pages?  Is this ODS HTML, or are you using one of the SAS web products, like SAS BI products or something?

Comment: No products, all I have is a about 20 SAS file with the styles and scripts.